# Safely return all lists in site collection that match criteria

Tags: security, list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm using the following code to get all "Announcement" lists in a Web Applications site collection.

Unfortunately, sometimes the current user does not have permission to that site and the page fails with an exception, even inside the try block.

What would be the right way to do the following safely for all users, where even an anonymous user would just get no results?

```
static public List<SPListMeta> AllSiteAnnouncementsLists()
{
    var returnList = new List<SPListMeta>();
    foreach (SPSite oSiteCollection in SPContext.Current.Web.Site.WebApplication.Sites)
    {
        var collWebs = oSiteCollection.AllWebs;
        try
        {
            foreach (SPWeb oWebsite in collWebs)
            {
                using (oWebsite)
                {
                    var collSiteLists = oWebsite.GetListsOfType(SPBaseType.GenericList);
                    returnList.AddRange(from SPList oList in collSiteLists where oList.Title == "Announcements" select new SPListMeta(oList));
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }

    }
    return returnList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me, though I do not know if it is the best way to do this.

```
    static public List<SPListMeta> AllSiteAnnouncementsLists()
    {
        var returnList = new List<SPListMeta>();

        var collWebs = SPContext.Current.Web.Site.WebApplication.Sites[0].OpenWeb().GetSubwebsForCurrentUser();
        if(SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.Open))
        {
            var collSiteLists = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.GetListsOfType(SPBaseType.GenericList);
            returnList.AddRange(from SPList oList in collSiteLists
                                where oList.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.ViewListItems)
                                && oList.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.Announcements
                                select new SPListMeta(oList));
        }
        foreach (SPWeb oWebsite in collWebs)
        {
            returnList.AddRange(WebRecursion.GetListsForCurrentWeb(oWebsite, SPListTemplateType.Announcements));
            foreach (SPWeb oSubSite in oWebsite.Webs)
            {
                returnList.AddRange(WebRecursion.GetListsForCurrentWeb(oSubSite, SPListTemplateType.Announcements));
            }
        }
        return returnList;
    }

    public static List<SPListMeta> GetListsForCurrentWeb(SPWeb oWebsite, SPListTemplateType type)
    {
        var returnList = new List<SPListMeta>();
        if (oWebsite.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.Open))
        {
            using (oWebsite)
            {
                var collSiteLists = oWebsite.Lists;
                returnList.AddRange(from SPList oList in collSiteLists
                                    where oList.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.ViewListItems)
                                    && oList.BaseTemplate == type
                                    select new SPListMeta(oList));
            }
        }
        return returnList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try give your code the right permission to execute.

```
using Microsoft.Sharepoint.Administrator;

 SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate(){

                // Your source code goes here
  });
```

Comment: RunWithElevatedPriviliges is the way to go - just keep in mind that the code is running with the web application user, so also anonymous users will be executed with those permissions.

Comment: This will returns all the results irrespective of the permissions of the user. I think it's not what the OP wants

Answer (score 1):

To get all items of the specific list type from the site collection you have to use SPSiteDataQuery. Each user will get only those items they have permissions.

```
     SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
     SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();

     //Ask for all lists created from the announcement template.
     query.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"104\" />";

     // Get the Title field. Define here all you need.
     query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />";

     // Set the sort order.
     query.Query = "<OrderBy>" + 
                       "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />" + 
                   "</OrderBy>";

     // Query all Web sites in this site collection.
     query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\" />";

     DataTable dt = web.GetSiteData(query);
     DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
```